# Grails 2.0 jQuery Mobile unresolved dependency

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-mobile

I have a Grails 1.3.7 project that uses the jQuery Mobile plugin that I'm upgrading it to Grails 2.0.1. Here's what I've done:

```
# grails upgrade  (runs with no issue)
# grails list-plugins --installed  (shows hibernate & tomcat but not my other plugins)
# grails install-plugin jquery-mobile  (no problem reported)
```

From this point forward, any command issues this error:

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.7.1: configuration not found in org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.7.1: 'master'. It was required from org.grails.plugins#jquery-mobile;1.0.4 compile
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

The plugin's dependency.groovy contains this line which I assume is the source of this issue but commenting this line out does not resolve the problem.

```
compile ":jquery:latest.integration"
```

Even after uninstalling the jquery-mobile plugin, the unresolved dependencies error remains.

I decided to restart the migration from a fresh git clone and followed [Peter Ledbrook's](http://pledbrook.github.com/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html) upgrade instructions. **I executed run-app without trying to resolve the missing plugins and I've gotten much further.**

Comment: Incidentally, thanks for the link to Peter Ledbrook's upgrade instructions!

Comment: No problem anymore.  After running upgrade, ignore the fact that list-plugins doesn't (yet) show all your plugins and do a run-app which will fixup the plugins.